# How can I use the CSV file loading functionality of Dygraphs myself (to load CSV data and then myself add a new series to it before chart rendering)?

Tags: csv, import, dygraphs

Since Dygraphs apparently does not have any functionality for adding separate series of data to a chart one at a time (but rather only loading all the data series of a chart at once from a CSV file, or an in-memory array of arrays) I'm looking to make some code to do this myself.

My reason? My problem/scenario is that I have a "base file" containing a series of data many million values large. I will then need to show many separate charts that display this large data series TOGETHER with a bunch of other respective smaller data series, and I'd very much rather not duplicate the large dataseries in a new CSV file on disk for each such chart, but rather first load the big "base data series" from the CSV "base file" directly from my Javascript, and then for each such chart integrate one such smaller data series with it before sending it off to rendering by means of a `new Dygraph(...)` call.

The CSV file loading functionality that already obviously exists somewhere inside the Dygraphs code is very nice, so I'd very much like to use it for this loading of the large "base data series" if possible, from a single separate CSV file.

So, in short, the question is:

How can I use the existing CSV file loading functionality of Dygraphs separately from inside my own code, in order to load arbitrary CSV files into the Dygraphs chart data array format in-memory, so that I can finally merge these multiple data series arrays using my own custom code?

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

```
loaded_data_series_1 = some_secret_internal_function_or_method_of_dygraphs('file1.csv');
loaded_data_series_2 = some_secret_internal_function_or_method_of_dygraphs('file2.csv');
merged_data_series = my_own_custom_dataseries_merging_code(loaded_data_series_1, loaded_data_series_2);
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('my_chart'), merged_data_series,{});
```

The key here would thus be to know what  `some_secret_internal_function_or_method_of_dygraphs()` should be replaced with for this to work.

Could the Dygraph devs or anyone else possibly point me in the right direction here?

(I tried to look inside the Dygraphs code myself, but unfortunately got lost pretty quickly due to insufficient Javascript coding skills on my side)